# Learning Entity Framework 6 command tree interceptors

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, interceptor

This is purely a learning experiment (yay science!).  This is not meant to actually be used anywhere.  I want to learn how EF6's command tree interceptors work.

I'm trying to modify the intercepted command tree to add a "IsActive = 1" filter to all queries.  I've noticed a serious deficiency in documentation on this sort of thing.  Two questions:

How do I selectively intercept command trees for say, entities that implement an interface (such as `IHasAnActiveProperty`)?  Right now I note that the interceptor is intercepting queries for the history context, which has nothing to do with my `MyEntity`.

How do I add my filter to all queries?

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyEntity> Entities { get; set; }

    public MyDbContext() : base("default") { }


    public MyDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString) {}
}

public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyConfiguration()
    {
        AddInterceptor(new MyInterceptor());
    }
}

public class MyInterceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor
{
    public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    {
        var query = interceptionContext.Result as DbQueryCommandTree;
        if (query != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("##################");
            Debug.WriteLine("DataSpace: {0}", interceptionContext.Result.DataSpace);
            Debug.WriteLine(query.ToString());

            query.Query.Accept(new MyVisitor());
        }
    }
}
```

This is where the meat of the question lies.  As you can see I've identified a few things that need to be included, but I don't have a clue how to put these things together.

```
public class MyVisitor : BasicExpressionVisitor
{
    public override void Visit(DbFilterExpression expression)
    {
        // add WHERE [IsActive] = 1
        /* Building blocks:
         *      DbExpressionBuilder.Equal
         *      DbExpressionBuilder.True
         *      DbExpressionBuilder.And   --- only when a filter expression already exists
         */

        var isActiveProperty = expression.Property("IsActive");
        var equalExp = DbExpressionBuilder.Equal(isActiveProperty, DbExpressionBuilder.True);
    }
}
```

Supposing we had this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var entities = ctx.Entities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "amy");
            Console.WriteLine(entities);
        }
    }
}
```

This query results in this command tree:

```
DbQueryCommandTree
|_Parameters
|_Query : Collection{Record['Id'=Edm.Int32, 'Name'=Edm.String, 'IsActive'=Edm.Boolean]}
  |_Project
    |_Input : 'Limit1'
    | |_Limit
    |   |_Filter
    |   | |_Input : 'Extent1'
    |   | | |_Scan : CodeFirstDatabase.MyEntity
    |   | |_Predicate
    |   |   |_
    |   |     |_'amy'
    |   |     |_=
    |   |     |_Var(Extent1).Name
    |   |_1
    |_Projection
      |_NewInstance : Record['Id'=Edm.Int32, 'Name'=Edm.String, 'IsActive'=Edm.Boolean]
        |_Column : 'Id'
        | |_Var(Limit1).Id
        |_Column : 'Name'
        | |_Var(Limit1).Name
        |_Column : 'IsActive'
          |_Var(Limit1).IsActive
```

But I don't understand where to go from here.

Comment: The `ExpressionVisitor` was not designed to modify the expression, but to know of it's existance and/or log it.  If you want to modify the command you'll have to derrive from `IDbCommandInterceptor`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, that explains *so much*.

Comment: @Amy So did you ever get a working version of your code?  I'd be interested to learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following references to help me implement a custom "soft delete" interception mechanism :

- [Entity Framework: Building Applications with Entity Framework 6](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B417#fbid=) (as far as I remember, the part about interceptors is around min 20 with a focus on the `SCAN` node which should answer your question)
- [How can I suppress execution from an Entity Framework 6 IDbCommandTreeInterceptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24892763/1236044)
- [Missing EF Feature Workarounds: Filters](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/29/missing-ef-feature-workarounds-filters/) (with an interesting point about query caching issues in the comments)

Hope this will help